# Unknown Javadoc tag TYPE with generics

Tags: java, generics, javadoc

I have method with javadoc:

```
/**
 * Supplier interface mixed with {@link ServiceCast}.
 * @param <R> is <TYPE> of supplier.
 */
public interface ServiceCastSupplier<R> extends ServiceCast, Supplier<R> {

}
```

in pipeline I'm getting error:

```
error: unknown tag: TYPE
[ERROR]      * @param <R> is <TYPE> of supplier
```

r.

why it doesn't like `<R>`, what's wrong with it?

Comment: It's `<TYPE>` that it doesn't like. It is not one of the type variables.

Comment: Try with [`@literal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#literal) if you need it displayed with the angular brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to change the documentation to

```
/**
 * Supplier interface mixed with {@link ServiceCast}.
 * @param <R> is the type of supplier.
 */
```

i.e., remove `<TYPE>` entirely, just like the standard library does, unless it has an important meaning to your code.

If you really need to show the angular brackets, you can use [`{@literal}`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#literal)

```
/**
 * Supplier interface mixed with {@link ServiceCast}.
 * @param <R> is {@literal <TYPE>} of supplier.
 */
```